# use same function for several divs depending on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that works for some divs, every 2 seconds, inside of it I want to wait 1 second to call same method but giving other div, and effect, the issue is how can I wait that second (currently every 2 seconds all divs execute the effect, and I would like to execute in a 1 second row).

```
$(function () {
    index = 0;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (index > 10){ 
            index = 0;
        }    
        myFunction("so1", "flipping-right");
        //setTimeout(funcx, 1000);
        myFunction("so2", "flipping-left");        
        //setTimeout(funcx, 1000);
        myFunction("so3", "flipping-top");
        //setTimeout(funcx, 1000);
        myFunction("so4", "flipping-bottom");
        //setTimeout(funcx, 1000);
        myFunction("so5", "flipping-right");

        i++;
    }, 2000); 
});




myFunction = function (id, effect ) { 
    $('#' + id).toggleClass(effect);
}
```

Please take a look [at my code](http://jsfiddle.net/v2wxX/5/)

Comment: 2000 milliseconds != 1 second

Comment: I'm guessing it's something like this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2wxX/7/) ??

Comment: Is there any way to  make execute all of them in a row, (one second diference), when I see you fiddle all of them execute, then wait and execute again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right, the problem is you have function invocation and you need to pass the function itself. [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) accepts a function parameter so you need to pass a function to it .

Try (inside the `setInterval`)

```
setTimeout(function(){
    myFunction("so1", "flipping-right");
    myFunction("so2", "flipping-left");        
    myFunction("so3", "flipping-top");
    myFunction("so4", "flipping-bottom");
    myFunction("so5", "flipping-right");
}, 1000);
```

If you'd like to execute them one after the other you can do something like

```
 setTimeout(function(){
        myFunction("so1", "flipping-right");
 }, 1000);
 setTimeout(function(){
        myFunction("so2", "flipping-left");  
 }, 2000);
 setTimeout(function(){
        myFunction("so1", "flipping-right");
 }, 3000);
 setTimeout(function(){
       myFunction("so3", "flipping-top");
 }, 4000);
 setTimeout(function(){
        myFunction("so5", "flipping-right");
 }, 5000);
```

Here is [the fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/ncdWT/) assuming the second behavior is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to loop the animating, but either way, you should use `setTimeout` instead and call each element in a chain:

```
myFunction = function (id, effect ) { 
    var $elem = $('#' + id);

    if ($elem.length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $elem.toggle(effect);
            myFunction(nextID, nextFlippint);
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

What I would suggest is to store the effect on the element itself as in `data-effect="flipping-right"` because there does not seem to be any other sort of calculable order.  As for `nextID`, you can either use the `.next()` element instead, or you can add 1 to the current id.  If you want this to loop over, then reset the id to 1 if `$elem.length` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
index = 0;
var datas = [
["so1", "flipping-right"],
["so2", "flipping-left"],
["so3", "flipping-top"],
["so4", "flipping-bottom"],
["so5", "flipping-right"]
];
// 2sec to start animate
setTimeout(function  () {
    // 1sec loop
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (index > 10){ 
            index = 0;
        }    
        myFunction( data[i][0], data[i][1]);
        i++;
    }, 1000); 
},2000)
});

myFunction = function (id, effect ) { 
  $('#' + id).toggleClass(effect);
}
```

may look like this

Comment: I may did something wrong the code looks interesting but can not make it to work

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a little more control out of the timing sequence you can just pass the delay between elements to the function. This way you can tweak the timing between the iterations of the set.

```
myFunction = function ($flip, delay) { 
    setTimeout(function(){
        var effect = "flipping-" + $flip.attr('data-direction');
        $flip.toggleClass(effect);
    },delay);
} 

$(function () {
    var timer = 0;
    $("[data-direction]").each(function(){
        myFunction($(this),timer);
        timer += 1000;
    });
});
```